# Embedding Audiomack Player onto website using php

Tags: php, preg-match, embed

I use the following **preg match**

```
if (preg_match('![?&]{1}v=([^&]+)!', 'youtubeurl' . '&', $m)) $video_id = $m[1];
```

to get the youtube **V** value, store it in **$video_id** which I then add to an iframe;

```
<iframe width="100%" height="305" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<? echo $video_id; ?>?rel=2&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

to load a youtube video on my website. Am trying to use the same approach for Audiomack but their URL format is different.

Audiomack uses the following URL format;

```
https://www.audiomack.com/song/famous-dex/annoyed
```

And their iframe is as follows;

```
<iframe src="https://www.audiomack.com/embed/song/famous-dex/annoyed" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="110" scrollbars="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

How can I modify the above **preg_match** to obtain the last two strings from the URL together with the slash, store it in a variable and then call it from an iframe?

eg.

```
$url = 'https://www.audiomack.com/famous-dex/song/annoyed';    
if (preg_match('![?&]{1}v=([^&]+)!', '$url' . '&', $m)) $audio_id = $m[1];
```

and the value of **$audio_id** should return **song/famous-dex/annoyed**
then I can insert it into the iframe as such;

```
<iframe src="https://www.audiomack.com/embed/<? echo $audio_id; ?>" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="110" scrollbars="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$url = 'https://www.audiomack.com/embed4/famous-dex/annoyed';
if (preg_match('/.+\/(.+\/.+)$/', $url, $matches)) {
    $audio_id = $matches[1];
    echo $audio_id; // gives you famous-dex/annoyed
}
```

1. Match anything else till you reach the "/"
2. Capture any two characters, words, etc which are separated by a "/"
3. End the match search.

Without the "$" the search will fail, since in this context it is kind of  forcing the search to "start from the end, backwards".

Comment: Add a small explanation to your answer to explain why it works.

Comment: I've just added it. Thanks a lot @Morgoth.

Comment: Hey @Nelis Audiomack seem to have updated their embedding url by swapping the arrangement. Can you help?